# Is it safe to use an IdentityHashMap (in Java) for Long keys representing timestamps?

Tags: java, hashmap

In my Java program I have a List<Long> times with timestamps in milliseconds. For each time some value is associated (e.g. Map<Long, Float>). Right now I'm using a HashMap for this, but by profiling I have noticed putAll has the highest percentage selftime. So to optimize this I was wondering if I could use an IdentityHashMap instead, but is this safe? The result changed so it seems not, but why?

I have done this to check, but 'equal' stays false. Can someone explain this?

```
boolean equal = false;
for (int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < times.size(); j++) {
        if (times.get(i) == times.get(j)) {
            equal = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that fills the 'times' map.

Comment: 'times' is a list, not a map. Simply timestamps in milliseconds. A timestamp each 15 minutes.

Comment: What is the relation of this list to the maps you're mentioning, then?

Comment: No, you can't. The keys will be different objects and therefore they won't match. Though, the `equals` implementation of `Long` doesn't do much more than compare the values... So, I don't see much improvement in performance there.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevent for my question, but the list times simply contains all timestamps (used for many purposes). For an algorithm I need an associated value (e.g. moving average) for each timestamp.

Comment: @Bubletan, would it work for integers or some other object?

Comment: @Bubletan, how will the keys differ in an IdentityHashMap to a HashMap? It now works with a HashMap.

Comment: @marcbrouwer Yes, if the integers are within byte range. In that case, the instances will be taken from the `Integer` cache and will therefore be the same.

Comment: @Bubletan so in that case (since I dont care about the milliseconds) I could use timestamps in seconds as integer right?

Comment: @Bubletan, I don't think that is assured.  Maybe it works in conjunction with autoboxing, but certainly `new Integer(1)` must produce a distinct object every time it is evaluated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh yeah, you're right. It can still be used at private level though. Yet, there's almost no difference in performance anyway.

Comment: @marcbrouwer Maybe theoretically, but I would stick with the normal `HashMap`.

Comment: Assuming all timestamps (in seconds as integer) are unique, would an IdentityHashMap then be oke to use?

Comment: I'm curious, @marcbrouwer: how much performance improvement does `IdentityHashMap` in fact give you?

Comment: if performance of this map is really critical, find a map impl with primitive keys...

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I've just implemented IdentityHashMaps in 4 places. I would actually be possible to use this in more places. For a subanalysis with 101250 parameter combinations it takes 94s without IdentityHashMaps, with the IdentityHashMaps added in 4 places and obtaining the same result it takes 61s. The complete analysis has 8201250 parameter combinations, so this is a significant performance improvement. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Complete analysis estimate execution times are 7425s without IdentityHashMaps and 3267s with those 4 IdentityHashMaps. Assume this is with an average dataset size and I have to do this for 11 cases, it will save me almost 13 HOURS! Time reduced by ~54%

Answer (score 1):

> is [using an IdentityHashMap in place of a HashMap] safe?

No, not if the keys override `Object.equals()` and / or `Object.hashCode()`.

> The result changed so it seems not, but why?

The difference between `IdentityHashMap` and `HashMap` is that the former uses `System.identityHashCode()` and the `==` operator for hashing and comparing keys, whereas `HashMap` uses the keys' own `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for those purposes.  If the keys override `Object.equals()` then you can have two keys such that

```
k1.equals(k2) && (k1 != k2)
```

is `true`.  Such keys are distinct to an `IdentityHashMap`, but are equivalent to a `HashMap`.  Such pairs are very easy to obtain; for example:

```
Long k1 = new Long(1);
Long k2 = new Long(1);
```

will do.

`IdentityHashMap` is for the special case that you want every distinct object to be a distinct key, despite the objects' idea about their own equivalency.  If you aren't sure you need it, then you don't need it.  If `HashMap` serves your purposes appropriately, then you don't need and probably don't want `IdentityHashMap`.

The javadocs put it this way:

> **This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.**

(emphasis in the original)

Comment: In my case there are no 2 long value equal nor have the same hashcode. So why does the IdentityHashMap not give the same result? All keys are distinct.

I checked like this (sorry for layout, new here):
    boolean equal = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < times.size(); j++) {
                if (times.get(i).equals(times.get(j)) || times.get(i) == times.get(j)) {
                    equal = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Your test implies that your keys are a consecutive set of non-negative integers starting at `0`.  If that's really the case then why don't you lose the keys altogether and just use a `List`?

Comment: In any event, *of course* your `HashMap` contains no two keys that are `equals()` or `==` each other.  That's exactly the point.  The problem arises when you propose a new key for addition to the map, and especially when you want to retrieve a value from the map by key.  With a `HashMap`, you can retrieve your value via any key object that is `equals()` the one enrolled in the map.  With `IdentityHashCode` you must use the very same object.